# Count Unique Results in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IncidentStatus.IncidentStatusName, Incident.IncidentID AS Bob
FROM            Incident 
INNER JOIN      IncidentMember 
                 ON Incident.IncidentID = IncidentMember.IncidentId
INNER JOIN      IncidentStatus 
                 ON Incident.IncidentStatusID = IncidentStatus.IncidentStatusID
WHERE        (IncidentMember.MemberId = 6)
```

And the result is:

```
IncidentStatusName   Bob
---------------------------
Closed               9267
In Progress          9251
In Progress          9289
New                  7893
Resolved             7750
```

Required Result is:

```
IncidentStatusName   Bob
---------------------------
Closed               1
In Progress          2
New                  1
Resolved             1
```

Help Requested.

Comment: need sample data, table names with columns etc. telling us you got too many rows isn't helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT IncidentStatus.IncidentStatusName, COUNT(Incident.IncidentID) AS Bob  
  FROM Incident 
INNER JOIN IncidentMember ON Incident.IncidentID = IncidentMember.IncidentId 
INNER JOIN IncidentStatus ON Incident.IncidentStatusID = IncidentStatus.IncidentStatusID 
WHERE (IncidentMember.MemberId = 6)
GROUP BY IncidentStatus.IncidentStatusName
```

Or maybe you need `COUNT(DISTINCT Incident.IncidentID)` (depends on your table structure)

Comment: I concede. You were faster. :) +1

Comment: You have to be fast around here... :)

Answer (score 0):

take your PK field, Incident.IncidentID, out of the select distinct clause